# STM32F4Discovery, an HTTP server and a web page on the SD card

Tags: ethernet, stm32, sd

I have an [STM32F4Discovery board](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419), and I have implemented an HTTP server on it using the [LwIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP) v1.41 stack. I also have implemented a [microSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) card reader with SDIO and [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html), and USB FS as a mass storage device. All of this is working fine together.

Can I store the webpages on the SD card in binary format instead of using the `fsdata.c` inside the microcontroller flash? If so, how can I do that? Is there an example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

For example, when you receive request `GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1` you can check if such file exists, open it, sent relevant headers and file contents.

Web server demo from LwIP will require (as stated on http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Sample_Web_Server) extensive rewrite, but in custom HTTP server it is possible.